# Istringstream doesn't "walk" through the line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stringstream, istringstream

I'm trying to read in a feature vector file storing feature vectors in the following way:

> (label) (bin):(value) (bin):(value) etc.

like:

> -1 5:0.015748 6:0.0472441 7:0.0393701 8:0.00787402 12:0.0314961 13:0.0944882 14:0.110236 15:0.0472441 20:0.023622 21:0.102362 22:0.110236 28:0.015748 29:0.228346 30:0.125984

As you can see it's saved without the bins that have a value of 0 in them.

I tried reading them in with the following code:

```
int bin;
int label;
float value;
string small_char; -> change to char small_char to fix the problem

if(readFile.is_open())
  while(!readFile.eof()) {
    getline(readFile, line);
    istringstream stm(line);
    stm >> label;
    cout << label << endl;
    while(stm) {
          stm >> bin;
          stm >> small_char;
          stm >> value;
          cout << bin << small_char << value << endl;
    }
    cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
  } 
}
```

But for unknown reason the label gets read correctly, the first bin with value as well, but the following bins aren't being read at all.

The output of the above example line is:

```
-1
5:0.015748
5:0.015748
Press ENTER to continue
```

The same thing occurs for all lines that are following.

I'm using visual studio 10, if that matters in anyway.

Comment: One thing (unrelated to your problem though) is that you shouldn't use `while (readFile.eof())` (or the other status functions). Instead do `while (getline(readFile, line))`.

Comment: By the way, could you please edit your question to include the declarations of `label`, `bin`, `small_char` and `value`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The `getline` is on the file, not on `cin`.  He's just reading from `cin` to pause.

Comment: Without seeing the variable declarations, it's impossible to say. but off hand, I'd say that there is some sort of an error when reading the second bin.  You output the elements without checking that you've actually read them, so the last successful input will be output twice.  Your nested loop should be `while ( stm >> bin >> small_char >> value )`.  And of course, your outer loop should be `while ( getline( readFile, line )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested it myself it seems that you are not using correct types (as well as correct looping condition).

My test program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is("-1 5:0.015748 6:0.0472441 7:0.0393701 8:0.00787402 12:0.0314961 13:0.0944882 14:0.110236 15:0.0472441 20:0.023622 21:0.102362 22:0.110236 28:0.015748 29:0.228346 30:0.125984");

    int label;
    int bin;
    char small;
    double value;

    is >> label;
    std::cout << label << '\n';
    while (is >> bin >> small >> value)
    {
        std::cout << bin << small << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output from this program is:

```
-1
5:0.015748
6:0.0472441
7:0.0393701
8:0.00787402
12:0.0314961
13:0.0944882
14:0.110236
15:0.0472441
20:0.023622
21:0.102362
22:0.110236
28:0.015748
29:0.228346
30:0.125984
```

So make sure the variable types are correct, and change the looping to not get double last lines.

Comment: I was using a string as variable type for small_char, which is where the error occured I guess. Problem solved